Is the table environment in LaTeX a floating environment ? How to keep tables where we like?
Is the table environment in LaTeX a floating environment ? How to keep tables where we like?
A few days a friend helped me with inserting figures where we like using :
\usepackage{capt-of}

Will this work for table environment also?  Thanks!

table is a float and you really should start using floats properly instead of instisting on having them here. You don't see profesional publications with big holes in the test because the authors wanted the table *right here and there wasn't enough room. You want the table to be close by. So remember to use \begin{table}[htbp], the defaut does not include h so it will never be placed right here if there was room for it. It will be at the top, bottom or on a page of its own.

The only reason to use table is to allow its content to be moved, so if you do not want it to move, just use tabular directly, but be prepared for a lot more manual editing of the source file to obtain usable page breaks.  The code for table is unreleated to tabular layouts, just as the code for figure is unrelated to inclusion of images
